# Какое будущее у Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Здравствуйте! Помогите определится.
Недавно приступил к изучению веб-программирования, для серверной части выбрал PHP, а для клиентской, естественно - JavaScript. После небольшого ознакомления JS мне понравился больше чем PHP(какой-то он нудной). И вот теперь думаю, может стоит начать изучать вместо PHP NodeJS, чтобы уже полностью погрузится в одну технологию. Что Вы об этом думаете?

Comment: не связывайтесь с PHP, не доведет он до добра. Уж во всяком случае, не начинайте с него

Comment: Я считаю нужно учить то за что деньги платять. Потому-что изучив один язык, на нем долго не просидишь, хочется больше и дальше, и кругозор сразу расширяется. Так что пока nodeJS еще не всеми хостерами поддерживается лучше учить php/mysql/html/js/css как минимум, с помощью этого всего уже можно зарабатывать деньги чтобы эксперементировать над nodeJS
Нельзя делать ставки на один язык они мрут как котята в введре.  И nodejs скоро тоже всем надоест. Да и всякие GO, kotlin на подходе...

Comment: @DreamChild чем вам php не угодил? Сложно дается? 

По вопросу: у javascript'a выше уровень вхождения, дается не так просто. Можно написать приложение, которое будет лагать при каждом чихе, лишь чуть постараться надо. Да и отладка сложнее. (я про node.js). Ну а так - клевая штука ;-)

Comment: @Bimawa Это какие языки "мрут, как котята в ведре"? php или javascript? (Пока незаметно, хотя таким, как perl и php не грех бы и помочь).

Comment: @lampa тем, что очень уж способствует быдлокодингу. Тут, конечно, можно развести многостраничный спор, утверждая, что "главное - не то, какой язык, а то, какой программист", но в случае с начинающим программистом говорить об этом не приходится

Comment: @DreamChild а вы ходить-то тоже сразу научились? А что он способствует быдлокодингу - вам какая разница?

Comment: @lampa вы тут так злобствуете, будто я лично вас оскорбил. А что касается "ходить", то лучше уж научиться ходить вовремя, а не через n лет..или вовсе не научиться (переучиваться всегда сложнее, чем научиться с чистого лита), что зачастую бывает с пхпшниками. Это заодно и о том, чем плохо  способствование быдлокодингу

Comment: @DreamChild Вы прежде чем ходить нормально, ковыляли еще хрен знает сколько месяцев. Я вот и хочу знать, какое отношение к вам имеют быдлокодеры? А форматирование кода и логика работы тоже приходят не сразу. Всё формируется постепенно.

Comment: @lampa я вам говорю, что если взять сотню (тысячу, миллион)  начинающих программистов, и посадить их "начинать" с php, а также взять столько же таких же начинающих программистов и посадить их за что-нибудь более строгое и хорошо структурированное (условную java или delphi например), то в первом случае вы этих самых быдлокодеров (которые будут с удовольствием работать за кусок хлеба, после которых ничего нельзя будет сопровождать, которых впоследствии почти ничему нельзя будет научить, и за которыми вам же придется все переписывать), так вот, в первом случае их будет куда больше, чем во втором

Comment: бред. неверно.

Просто php несколько проще для старта, дает возможность быстрее получить результат и прощает некоторые ошибки. Человек обычно хочет за какое то приемлемое время получить результат.

Поэтому, если и сделать указанный эксперимент, то часть программистов с delphi/java/c++/haskell/любой_другой_правильный_язык перейдет на php. Так как php для них будет проще. Соответственно, на php будет много "плохих кодеров". Конечно, будут и обратные переходы на другие языки с php.

Но все вышесказанное не значит, что php чем то хуже/легче других языков. У него просто легче старт.

Comment: @KoVadim диванные аналитики, они такие. Никогда не пробовали, но обосрать - всегда.

Comment: а для фронта используете какой либо js фреймворк?

Comment: @KoVadim не согласен. Как там в анекдоте: "Могу копать, могу не копать -- А лестницу -- можешь? -- Могу, но долго копать". На php "долго копать". Изобразительные возможности хромают (много писать), от ошибок не защищает...

То, что ещё и долго работает -- это уже бонус.

Comment: @Dreamchild самые страшные примеры говнокода я видел на java, а недавно встретил и на питоне.

Comment: КАЖДЫЙ раз, когда вы говорите что "PHP - говно", где-то умирает котик.

Comment: @Construct Какой котик? Местный, недоедающий (@Котик_хочет_кушать) вроде жив... Вы уж так не пугайте, и хоть объясните механизм.

Comment: Внесу и я в свои войска в войну php нормален vs. вреден

В пхп используются глобальные переменные. Человек используя их заводит кашу в голове - вон напишу переменную и везде её увижу. Мозги отрафируются. В то время например java программист выдумывает хитрые  ходы, вроде - "хорошо бы этот класс впихнуть в тот пакет, чтобы ему те переменные не мешались". Мозги развиваются

Comment: @eicto важно не то, какой код позволяет писать язык, а то, как влияет язык на мозги

Comment: Трэшовый какой-то аргумент про глобальные переменные. С помощью **любого** языка можно написать write-only код, а можно написать хороший код. Например, читать тот же самый [`Symfony`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony) — одно удовольствие.

Comment: Повторюсь, важно не то, какой код позволяет писать язык, а как язык влияет на человека. Быдлокодер не напишет хороший код ни на каком языке

Answer (score 8, accepted):

я бы рекомендовал изучать оба в параллельном режиме, ибо:
во-1, пхп еще долго не умрет и будет востребован.
во-2, ноде.жс также будет пользоваться спросом ввиду своей производительности и легкости

*(сам с 2004 года на пхп, сейчас делаю некоторые модули на ноде.жс, поскольку пхп не успевает кое-где..)*

Comment: Спасибо! Вопросов больше не имею:)

Comment: например? где не успевает? расскажите по подробнее

Comment: "не успевает" например там, где нужен рилтайм - чаты, интерактивные игрульки и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Изучайте Python,а затем и фреймворк Django.
Ну а Ноду,если собираетесь создавать асинхронные фигнюшки.

Answer (score 0):

Если для фана - то конечно изучайте что то одно. Если Вы планируете сделать программирование Вашей работой, то ещё много чего нужно выучить (например ещё MySQL).

**upd**

На [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/163045/) проскочила статья, где показано, как на базе nodejs делают кроссплатформенные приложения.